# can't understand why 's is in this sentence

Tags: apostrophe

In the sentence "Foreign visitors are only allowed one month's residence", why is 's used? I found this sentence in an old version of the Oxford Advanced Learner's dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a paraphrase of *a residence of one month*, so it's possessive.

Since this is shown *only* in writing, many people are not aware of it, and the possessive is often not marked, especially in the plural (so you see *three years experience* as commonly as *three years' experience*). But the formal stylebooks tell you you need it.

Comment: So all of these are correct? right? one month's residence, one month residence , a one-month residence

Comment: The first and third are fine. Some people will object to the second.

Comment: When I said that people often don't bother to mark the possessive, I was thinking of plural cases, where there is already an "s", and the only question is whether to write _three years_ or _three years'_ (or even _three year's_). Where it's _one_, I think most English speakers will **say** "one month's residence", however they spell it.